# on completion of steps add TICK instead of plus in bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion, which has dropdown. I have dependent dropdowns where the second dropdown comes after selection in the first dropdown.

So once both the dropdown gets a value, I have a a button, On its click I want to have a TICK mark instead of plus after the collapse of the accordion.

```
<div class="accordionButton">
  <span>Accordion Button</span><span class="plusMinus">+</span>
</div>

<div class="accordionContent">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
</div>

<div class="accordionButton">
    <span>Accordion Button</span><span class="plusMinus">+</span>
</div>

  <div class="accordionContent">
    <p>Stuff in the Accordion</p>
  </div>
```

PS: My code is completely customized so not able to get a proper fidlde ready. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Na5FY/203/) as a reference.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below supposing your button on which tick should be shown has id "tickme"

```
$('#tickme').click(function(){
   $('.accordionButton .plusMinus').html("<img src='tick.png'>");
})
```

Comment: did it like this. But again, When I open the same dropdown, It should show the PLUS.

`$('#displaycorrect').css("display", "block");
       $('#displaybaseminus').css("display", "none");
       $('#displaybaseplus').css("display", "none");`


This is how I am doing at the moment. On click the above steps